# Spring security config is not working for the <tx:annotation-driven> tag. Giving compilation error

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am getting this compilation error:::

cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'tx:annotation-driven'.

My dispatcher servlet xml is :::

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"  
        xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx  
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:resources/database.properties" />
        <context:component-scan base-package="com.suva.*" />
         <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="hibernateTransactionManager"/>  

        <bean
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
            <property name="prefix">
                <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
            </property>
            <property name="suffix">
                <value>.jsp</value>
            </property>
        </bean>
<bean id="hibernateTransactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />    </bean>



     <bean id="dataSource"  
      class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">  
      <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driver}" />  
      <property name="url" value="${database.url}" />  
      <property name="username" value="${database.user}" />  
      <property name="password" value="${database.password}" />  
     </bean>  



     <bean id="sessionFactory"  
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">  
      <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />  
      <property name="hibernateProperties">  
       <props>  
        <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>  
        <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>  
        <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>      
       </props>  
      </property>  
     </bean>  

    </beans>
```

My web.xml is::

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

    <display-name>Spring MVC Application</display-name>

    <!-- Spring MVC -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Loads Spring Security config file -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Spring Security -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

spring-security.xml :::

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd  
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security  
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">

    <security:http auto-config="true">
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/admin/**"
            access="ROLE_USER" />
    </security:http>

    <security:authentication-manager>
        <security:authentication-provider>
            <!-- <security:user-service>
                <security:user name="user" password="pass"
                    authorities="ROLE_USER" />
                <security:user name="suva" password="123" authorities="ROLE_USER" />

            </security:user-service>-->

            <security:jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"    
      users-by-username-query="select username, password, active from users where username=?"   

  />  

        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>

</beans>
```

My controller::

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping(value = { "/", "/welcome**" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView welcomePage() {

        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
        model.addObject("title", "Spring Security Hello World");
        model.addObject("message", "This is welcome page!");
        model.setViewName("hello");
        return model;

    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/admin**", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView adminPage() {

        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
        model.addObject("title", "Spring Security Hello World");
        model.addObject("message", "This is protected page!");
        model.setViewName("admin");

        return model;

    }

}
```

I am using the below jars::

```
commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
jstl-1.2.jar
org.springframework.aop-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar
org.springframework.asm-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar
org.springframework.aspects-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar
org.springframework.beans-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar
org.springframework.context.support-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar
org.springframework.context-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar
org.springframework.core-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar
org.springframework.expression-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar
org.springframework.transaction-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar
org.springframework.web.servlet-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar
org.springframework.web-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar
spring-security-config-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-core-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-tx-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar
```

I have spring-tx-3.0 jar and ther other spring config jars in my classpath..

Please help me guys i am totally confused with this..struggling for 2weeks..not getting any solution.

Comment: Do you have your code on GitHub or something?

Comment: Hi @geoand thanks for the reply..i dont have the code in github. but i can give you the code here itself. Actually i have a simple spring security login application which i am going to integrate with db through hibernate. You solved my error last time regarding that simple application.so i think u already have the code. If you dont have please tell me i will upload it here..

Comment: Hi, last time I was on a different computer so I don't have your code. Go ahead and upload it somewhere and I when I have the chance I will download it and try to figure out what's going on.

Comment: ok i am updating that on this question thread only..please point me out where i am wrong.

Comment: What you have posted here is all your code? How about the jars? Which ones are you using?

Comment: yes nothing ather than this.. actually i am just building this to a db login project.. i am getting the compilation error.. I am editing the questions with the name of the jars.

Comment: i am extending the small spring-security application to a login project authenticated from the DB using hibernate. Please help i am learning the spring security

Comment: I haven't had the time to check this yet. I will let you know when I get a chance to look at it

Comment: yea its okk... please check and update in this thread..one more thing other than this, can u please suggest a good tutorial on spring security

Comment: Check out this series http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/spring-security-tutorials/

Comment: Could you please provide a zipped version of the code in some upload service, because I want the environment to be exactly the same?